# In azure functions, my function is working but default url is not working

Tags: python, azure-functions

**this is my code :**
I wrote this code in azure functions.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    document = ["Bestuur","Cultuur en recreatie","Economie"]
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function defined the document.')
    req_body = req.get_json()
    document = req_body if req_body else document
    # if req_body:
    #     document.update(req_body)
    # logging.info(f"Document: {document}")
    
    if document:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {document}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a document in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**this is the answer:**
HTTP response code
200 OK
HTTP response content
Hello, ['Bestuur', 'Cultuur\xa0en\xa0recreatie', 'Economie']. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.

**but url is not working:**

This page isn’t workingdm-weu-functionapp1.azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

how can i manage this situation?

I am expecting a solution and the explanation of the reason of this problem

Comment: Hi, could you also provide function.json file associated wit it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your Function code in my Local environment and received the same error when I browsed the local function URL, Refer below:-

[image]

**By default your Function expects  JSON Body in the request.**

I used the same URL with JSON Body as a Get/Post request and got the below output:-

[image]

Now, I deployed the same Function to my Azure Function app:-

[image]

I browsed the Function URL in my Browser and I received the same error:-

[image]

When I raised a same request with Postman by passing JSON Body, I got the expected results, Refer below:-

[image]

**In Portal:-**

[image]

[image]